# Problem with multi row table

Tags: tables, multirow

I'm trying to make this work, but the small cells don't show their content

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines, colspec={ll}}
\SetCell[r=6]{} Expression
    & \SetCell[r=3]{} Modality
    & P                         \\
    & O                         \\
    & A                         \\
    & \SetCell[r=3]{} Expressive Symbols
    & P                         \\
    & O                         \\
    & A                         \\
\end{tblr}
\caption{The Audit CheckList}
\label{table:DesignPrinciples}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 This looks like code we can compile : )

Comment: I'm very sorry about the previous ones

Comment: I cannot find what's the problem ? any idea ?

Comment: Please be patient, the experts on multirows or multicols will answer soon. // Perhaps it‘s a good idea to state meanwhile in the QUESTION, why you want tabularray: there are alternatives which may be easier to use.

Comment: Thank you, yep I will search for that as well

Comment: Just to remind you: we tend NOT to chat here … i.e. tend to comment less ;-)

Comment: You specify only two columns, but table has three. So instead of  `ll` you should write `lll` or `{*{3}{l} }` ...

Comment: Beside as stated in aforementioned my comment, you need to care that in each row you have all ampersands as should be according to declared columns. In your case in each row should be two ampersands.

Comment: Thank you but this question wasn't my problem

My problem is this https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/692120/trying-to-convert-multi-row-table-to-multi-row-multi-column/692128#692128

Do you have a solution for it ?

Answer (score 1):

You want three columns, but you are only specifying two:  `{ll}` should be `{lll}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines, colspec={lll}}
\multirow[c]{6}{2cm}{Expression} & \multirow[c]{3}{3cm}{Modality} & P   \\
   & & O  \\
   & & A  \\
    & \multirow[c]{3}{1.5cm}{Expressive Symbols} & P \\
   & & O  \\
   & & A  \\
\end{tblr}
\caption{The Audit CheckList}
\label{table:DesignPrinciples}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

You could also use `\multirow`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines, colspec={lll}}
\multirow[c]{6}{2cm}{Expression} & \multirow[c]{3}{3cm}{Modality} & P   \\
   & & O  \\
   & & A  \\
    & \multirow[c]{3}{1cm}{Expressive Symbols} & P \\
   & & O  \\
   & & A  \\
\end{tblr}
\caption{The Audit CheckList}
\label{table:DesignPrinciples}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Which gives you slightly different output:

[image]

Comment: You use quite old `tabularray` package that it still support `multirow command`. Versions from last two years require, that you use `SetCell[r=6]{l} <cell content>`  as OP correctly use in his question.

Comment: Thanks would you please check my other question, because it's somehow related and that is the structure I want: here , thanks for this one, I will accept it https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/692120/trying-to-convert-multi-row-table-to-multi-row-multi-column/692128#692128