# Trying to convert multi row table to multi row + multi column

Tags: tables, overleaf, multicolumn, multirow

I have this table

[image]

I'm trying to convert it to this

[image]

my code is this

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines, colspec={ll}}
\SetCell[r=6]{} Expression
    & \SetCell[r=3]{} Modality
    & P                         \\
    & O                         \\
    & A                         \\
    & \SetCell[r=3]{} Expressive Symbols
    & P                         \\
    & O                         \\
    & A                         \\
\end{tblr}
\caption{The Audit CheckList}
\label{table:DesignPrinciples}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

**UPDATE:**

So far

I don't know how to force rows with just 3 elements to divide by 3
and avoid any empty cell
Also the first column whatever I do, I cannot expand it to make a room for text

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{ccccccc}[hvlines]
\Block{4-2}{Expressiveness} &       & \Block{1-5}{Modality} \\
               &       &  P & O & A &  & \\
               &       & \Block{1-5}{Expressive Symbols} \\
               &       &  P & O & A &  & \\
\Block{6-2}{Replication} &       & \Block{1-5}{Placeholders} \\
               &       &  P & O & A & S & F\\
               &       & \Block{1-5}{Stacking} \\
               &       &  P & O & A &  & \\
               &       & \Block{1-5}{Afixing} \\
               &       &  P & O &  &  & \\
\Block{8-2}{Narration} &       & \Block{1-5}{Storyline Formation} \\
               &       &  1 & 2 & 3 & & \\
               &       & \Block{1-5}{Block Formation} \\
               &       &  (1 , 1) & (1 , 2) & (2 , 1) &  & \\
               &       & \Block{1-5}{Group Composition} \\
               &       &  P & O &  &  & \\
               &       & \Block{1-5}{Frame Fixation} \\
               &       &  P & O & A & Grouped P & Grouped A\\
\Block{8-2}{Connection} &       & \Block{1-5}{Progression} \\
               &       &  P & O & A & & \\
               &       & \Block{1-5}{Transition} \\
               &       &  P & O & A & & \\
               &       & \Block{1-5}{Aggregation} \\
               &       &  P & O & A & & \\
               &       & \Block{1-5}{Execution} \\
               &       &  P & O & A & & \\
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

**UPDATE2 Thanks to F. Pantigny:**

The problems are the empty cells

How can I force the small cell that expand all the way and fill the space without empty cell

for example divided by 2, 3, 4, 5

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{lccccc}[hvlines,cell-space-limits=3pt]
\Block{4-1}{Expressiveness} & \Block{1-5}{Modality} \\
               &  P & O & A \\
               & \Block{1-5}{Expressive\\ Symbols} \\
               &  P & O & A \\           
\Block{6-1}{Replication} & \Block{1-5}{Placeholders} \\
               &  P & O & A & S & F\\
               & \Block{1-5}{Stacking} \\
               &  P & O & A \\
               & \Block{1-5}{Affixing} \\
               &  P & O \\
\Block{8-1}{Narration} & \Block{1-5}{Storyline Foundation} \\
               &  1 & 2 & 3\\
               & \Block{1-5}{Block Formation} \\
               &  (1 , 1) & (1 , 2) & (2 , 1) \\
               & \Block{1-5}{Group Composition} \\
               &  P & O \\  
               & \Block{1-5}{Frame Fixation} \\
               &  P & O & A & Grouped P & Grouped O\\
\Block{8-1}{Connection} & \Block{1-5}{Progression} \\
               &  P & O & A \\
               & \Block{1-5}{Transition} \\
               &  P & O & A \\
               & \Block{1-5}{Aggregation} \\
               &  P & O & A \\  
               & \Block{1-5}{Execution} \\
               &  P & O & A \\  
\end{NiceTabular}\newline\newline\newline


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, this can be obtained by nesting `tabular` in `tblr` cells For example, as starting point:

**Edit:** from OP comment follows, the table in nested `tabular`s hasn't vertical lines, so code is now a wee bit simpler:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines, colspec={lc}, 
             row{even} = {rowsep=0pt}
            }
\SetCell[r=4]{} Expression
    & Modality              \\
    &   \begin{tabular}{@{} *{3}{w{c}{3.33 em}} @{}} % 3.33 = 10/3
        P & O & A                         
        \end{tabular}       \\
    & Expressive Symbols    \\
    &   \begin{tabular}{@{} *{5}{w{c}{2em}} @{}} % 2 = 10/5
        P & O & A & S & F
        \end{tabular}       \\
\end{tblr}
\caption{The Audit CheckList}
\label{table:DesignPrinciples}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks when I try it mine doesn't have the lines between P, O, A
Any package missing ?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/T9PDW5k look plz

Comment: @KamranAsgari, on images on your question are shown ... Without them the solution is even simpler. See edited answer

Answer (score 2):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{lw{c}{5cm}}[hvlines,cell-space-limits=3pt]
\Block{4-1}{Expressiveness} & Modality \\
               &  \omit\hfil P\hfil\vrule\hfil O\hfil\vrule\hfil A\hfil \\
               & Expressive Symbols \\
               &  \omit\hfil P\hfil\vrule\hfil  O\hfil\vrule\hfil A\hfil \\           
\Block{6-1}{Replication} & Placeholders \\
               &  \omit\hfil P\hfil\vrule\hfil O\hfil\vrule\hfil A\hfil\vrule\hfil S\hfil\vrule\hfil F\hfil \\
               &  Stacking \\
               &  \omit\hfil P\hfil\vrule\hfil O\hfil\vrule\hfil A\hfil \\
               &  Affixing \\
               &  \omit\hfil P\hfil\vrule\hfil O\hfil \\
\Block{8-1}{Narration} & Storyline Foundation \\
               &  \omit\hfil 1\hfil\vrule\hfil 2\hfil\vrule\hfil 3\hfil \\
               &  Block Formation \\
               &  \omit\hfil (1 , 1)\hfil\vrule\hfil (1 , 2)\hfil\vrule\hfil (2 , 1)\hfil \\
               &  Group Composition \\
               &  \omit\hfil P\hfil\vrule\hfil O\hfil \\  
               &  Frame Fixation \\
               &  \omit\hfil P\hfil\vrule\hfil O\hfil\vrule\hfil A\hfil\vrule\hfil Grouped P\hfil\vrule\hfil Grouped O\hfil \\
\Block{8-1}{Connection} & Progression \\
               &  \omit\hfil P\hfil\vrule\hfil O\hfil\vrule\hfil A\hfil \\
               &  Transition \\
               &  \omit\hfil P\hfil\vrule\hfil O\hfil\vrule\hfil A\hfil \\
               &  Aggregation \\
               &  \omit\hfil P\hfil\vrule\hfil O\hfil\vrule\hfil A\hfil \\  
               &  Execution \\
               &  \omit\hfil P\hfil\vrule\hfil O\hfil\vrule\hfil A\hfil \\  
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: Nice solution +1

Comment: Thank you
How can I have 5 cells under modality and 3 cells under Expressive symbols

the maximum is 5 and the minum is 2

Comment: I really appreciate anyone answer this question, Tomorrow I need to upload my Thesis and this is the only table remained, If I cannot solve I have to design it (which I'm very good at) but I really prefer LateX :)